# How to fetch a recursive relationship with Hibernate when a parent has no child items (Left Join)?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, recursion

I have this native query:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.*, cc.* FROM content c1, content c2, content_content cc, content_containers r
    WHERE c1.id = r.parent
    AND c2.id = r.child
    AND cc.content_col_id = r.parent
    AND r.root = :id
```

Where content_containers is a recursive Postgres view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW content_containers AS
WITH RECURSIVE containers(parent, child, index, root, depth) AS ( 
    SELECT content_col_id, content_id, container_index, content_col_id, 1
        FROM content_content
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.child, l.content_id, l.container_index, root, depth + 1
        FROM containers c, content_content l
        WHERE c.child = l.content_col_id
)  
SELECT parent, child, index, root, depth
    FROM containers
```

What content_containers gives me is the ability to table under each 'root' all the parent/child relationships that exist.

The 'Content' class can hold a list called a 'container' of further Content. In this way, my content is can be modelled as a tree:

```
public class Content {
  protected List<Content> container;
  ... // More fields
```

The query works by joining two content items with their many-to-many list mapping created by Hibernate 'content_content' and uses the recursive query to allow me to only select content appearing under the specified root.

The problem is, when a piece of content has not children, it is not selected at all, since their is no parent/child relationship in the content_container query.

How do I fix this? Will a 'left join' with null content c2, and null many-to-many list relationship work with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the join relationship (cc) and the child item (c2) are null, then Hibernate correctly interprets this as the recursive list of items being empty.

I have to change the recursive query to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW content_containers AS
WITH RECURSIVE containers(parent, child, index, root, depth) AS ( 
    SELECT c.id, cc.content_id, cc.container_index, c.id, 1 FROM content c
       LEFT JOIN content_content cc
       ON cc.content_col_id = c.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.child, l.content_id, l.container_index, root, depth + 1
        FROM containers c, content_content l
        WHERE c.child = l.content_col_id
)  
SELECT parent, child, index, root, depth
    FROM containers
```

And the native query that joins with it to:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.*, cc.* FROM content c1
    JOIN content_containers r ON c1.id = r.parent
    LEFT JOIN content c2 ON c2.id = r.child
    LEFT JOIN content_content cc ON cc.content_col_id = r.parent AND cc.content_id = r.child
    WHERE r.root = :id
    ORDER BY r.depth
```

This means that the recursive query returns a root and a parent, even when there are no child items, so can always JOIN to that without it being a LEFT JOIN. LEFT JOINs are then used in the native query to select child items and the list, only when they are available.

Feeling quite pleased with this, the general recursive query can be joined to to re-use it in all sorts of queries.

I used an ORDER BY depth, so that the root item comes out on top, and can then be picked from the list of results as item 0. Not sure if that, or a scan through the list in Java code would be better, but at least it all works now with a single query.